# Me sale error 273

Tags: pseint

Algoritmo  Figcircular

```
Definir radio, numpi Como Real;
Definir Perimetro,Area,Volumen Como Real; π
Escribir "Ingrese el radio del círculo";
Leer radio;

numpi<-3.1415;
Perimetro <- 2*numpi*radio;
Area <- numpi*radio*radio;
Volumen <- radio;

Escribir 'El perimetro de la circunferencia es';
Escribir Perimetro;
Escribir 'El area es';
Escribir Area;
Escribir 'El volumen es';
Escribir Volumen;
```

FinAlgoritmo

Comment: Dar una mejor explicacion para que puedan ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

el error que mencionas, es el siguiente:

```
ERROR 273: Debe haber un Proceso.
```

Esto ocurre por una mala sintaxis en el pseudocódigo.
Por alguna razón, tienes a `π` en esta línea:

```
Definir Perimetro,Area,Volumen Como Real; π
```

Cosa que PseInt no puede soportar. Si nos deshacemos de el, y sus espacios, tu código funciona a la perfección:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, aunque realmente no entiendo la pregunta:

```
Proceso AreaOfACircle
    Escribir Sin Saltar "Introduce el valor del radio:";
    Leer radius;
    area <- 3.14159265358979323846*radius*radius;
    Escribir "valor del area: ", area;
FinProceso
```